# Http operation error please help to solve the issues?

Tags: java, http, java-me, nokia, mobile-application

Im developing a mobile application using j2me.
  In my i send the data to server and receive data from server.
  I put a vodafone Sim in "nokia c2" mobile and run the application,then the network error is occured (java.io.IOException :81 - Http Operation).
  But i run the same application with the same sim in the mobile "sony ericsson -z530i" the my application runs correctly.
  Please tell me why the application not run correctly in nokia mobile & how to solve the issues.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Is it possible to debug your application, somehow?

Comment: Im a registered user of this site.Now im in office.In office they had some firewall.That firewall prevents the login to any site.So im not able to login.So i add my points through answer like an unregistered user.Adding comments required login.So dont mistake me. Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues:

- Your application doesn't have permission to connect to the internet
- Check if other app can connect to internet in the same phone
- Check for the GPRS conf settings

Answer (score 1):

As i understood all java apps on your nokia can't connect to network. So check your network connection settings for java (not for your default browser).